# Queue TFS 2012 build from Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jenkins, tfs, msbuild

Is it possible to trigger a TFS build from Jenkins. I have found that there is a plugin in Jenkins which can be used to trigger build [Link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md). But not sure if it can actually trigger build in TFS or it actually runs a MSBUILD on the TFS source, and does not invoke a TFS build which uses the build controller architecture for the build.

Please help me with the information , if anyone has worked on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin is used to get resource from TFS and trigger a build in Jenkins as Dylan Smith mentioned. If you want to trigger a build in TFS from Jenkins , you can add a "Execute Windows batch command" build step and use [TFSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181742(v=vs.100).aspx) command to queue a build in TFS.

```
TFSBuild start /collection:teamProjectCollectionUrl /builddefinition:definitionSpec [/droplocation:droplocation] /getoption:getoption] [/customgetversion:versionSpec] [/priority:priority] [/requestedfor:userName] [/msbuildarguments:args] [/shelveset:shelvesetName [/checkin]] [/silent] [/queue]
```

[image]

Comment: The TFSBuild command is for TFS 2010. Do we have anything in TFS2012. Basically i am looking to start a nightly build from Jenkins and get the result (whether the build is success or failure) based on this i will execute some command to deploy.

Comment: I did not find any MSDN doc that says that TFSBuild can be run from TFS 2012. Also do you have any idea if i can get the build result.

Comment: You can get the build status (Pass or Fail) from the command and the Jenkins job will be pass/fail base on the status. I don't have TFS 2012 but I'm using TFS 2015. I added a screenshot for this, you can refer to it in my answer for details.