# How to trigger TFS build manually from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs, build-automation, tfvc

I have a Jenkins job where TFVC(nothing but TFS) plugin installed with required information.And I am able to trigger the build after each check-in and periodically(like every 4 hours). But I wanted to trigger build from Jenkins manually like When i click on Build now, it have to check out the latest code and do build in TFS. Can someone help me here please

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Server plugin for Jenkins allows you to use a TFVC repository as an SCM in Jenkins jobs. At the moment, this plugin supports:

- Retrieving read-only copies of files and folders from a TFVC
  repository.
- Polling a TFVC repository to automatically start builds when there
  are changes.
- Links from the Jenkins change sets to the TFVC repository web
  interface. (Also known as a repository browser)
- Creating a label in the TFVC repository

You can't trigger TFS build from Jenkins by default. But you can do customization on Jenkins side with [TFS REST api](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) to trigger build on TFS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAML build, you can add a "Execute Windows batch command" build step to call [TFSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181742(v=vs.100).aspx) command to trigger a TFS Build. Refer to this question for details: [Queue TFS 2012 build from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003039/queue-tfs-2012-build-from-jenkins/36007057#36007057).

If you are using vNext build, you can create a PowerShell script and use it in Jenkins task to trigger TFS build via Rest API as Cece mentioned.